# How to get all users in a Gitlab repo?

Tags: curl, gitlab-ce

We host our own Gitlab-CE repo. How can I get a list of all the users? I do..

```
$ curl -H "Project-Token: dkjdlkfjlfj" https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/users
```

but because of pagination, I can only get 20 of the them, which is the default. How can I get all the users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot disable pagination completely** for the GitLab API.

However, you can [increase the max number of returned results from 20 to 100](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#pagination) via the `per_page` URL parameter:

```
$ curl -H "Project-Token: dkjdlkfjlfj" https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/users?per_page=100
```

After that, it's a matter of firing off multiple requests to get all users.

Comment: Yep. I'd have to write a loop. If I can get 100 (max) per page, I'd have to know how many users there are if I write a loop so I know how/when to end the loop correct?

Comment: Check out the doc page I linked, you can find the total number of pages in the response headers